Lahman issue with setnames()
I'm running lahman to test out some general baseball data and get a feel for what I have access to. I used these packages a few months ago and picked it back up today. I had to update R and RStudio in the process, so everything is up to date now.
library(baseballr)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(Lahman)

playerid_lookup(last_name = "Cole", first_name = "Gerrit")

gcole <- statcast_search_pitchers(start_date = "2023-03-01",
                         end_date = "2023-11-01",
                         fangraphs_id = 13125)


> gcole <- statcast_search_pitchers(start_date = "2023-03-01",
+                          end_date = "2023-11-01",
+                          fangraphs_id = 13125)
trying URL 'https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/statcast_search/csv?all=true&hfPT=&hfAB=&hfBBT=&hfPR=&hfZ=&stadium=&hfBBL=&hfNewZones=&hfGT=R%7CPO%7CS%7C&hfC&hfSea=2023%7C&hfSit=&hfOuts=&opponent=&pitcher_throws=&batter_stands=&hfSA=&player_type=pitcher&hfInfield=&team=&position=&hfOutfield=&hfRO=&home_road=&game_date_gt=2023-03-01&game_date_lt=2023-11-01&hfFlag=&hfPull=&metric_1=&hfInn=&min_pitches=0&min_results=0&group_by=name&sort_col=pitches&player_event_sort=h_launch_speed&sort_order=desc&min_abs=0&type=details'
Content type 'application/download; charset=utf-8' length 14383950 bytes (13.7 MB)
downloaded 13.7 MB

Error in setnames(x, value) : 
  Can't assign 92 names to a 94-column data.table

it's just step one and there's already issues. i have no idea what's causing this. i would like it to just pull Gerrit Cole's 2023 season info into a dataset.

Seems like this is a bug in baseballr. If you install the most recent version from Github, not CRAN, sounds like it's fixed. To do that, install.packages("remotes") and then remotes::install_github("BillPetti/baseballr") ought to do it.

this worked perfectly, thank you so much
